# What is the equivalent of cast.player.api.Player live stream options on CAF receiver?

Tags: chromecast, google-cast, google-cast-sdk, caf-receiver-sdk

Right now using the cast reference player I pass `Infinity` as the second parameter on `cast.player.api.Player.load()` when I want to play live content. How can I accomplish that with the CAF receiver?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You should use chrome.cast.media.StreamType.LIVE as the media type in the load request.

Comment: Can I do it on the sernder on the `setStreamType()` method of `MediaInfo`?

Comment: I'm doing this on `setStreamType()` but it isn't working.

Comment: I think the answer might be `startAbsoluteTime` but it doesn't seem to work with `Infinity`.

Comment: If you are still experiencing issues, file a bug and provide a sample stream: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:190205%20status:open&s=modified_time:desc

Comment: It is filed but with a sample that isn't exactly live since live events end but it is a good long chunk of a live stream.

Comment: You should be able to do it either at the sender level or modify the `mediaInfo` object when you get a `LoadRequest`.  https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/reference/caf_receiver/cast.framework.messages.MediaInformation#streamType

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
playerManager.setMessageInterceptor(
    cast.framework.messages.MessageType.LOAD, function (loadRequestData) {
    loadRequestData.currentTime = Infinity;
    return loadRequestData;
    }
);
```

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/78293897?pli=1